# Is it correct to say "Do not duplicate the information, add only new one"?

Tags: nouns, numbers, uncountable-nouns

Information is an uncountable noun. Therefore, is it correct to refer to it with a number one as in: do not duplicate the information, add only new one?

Comment: You've answered this already yourself when you state that information is uncountable. No.

Comment: The *one* here does not refer to 'information,' it refers to what is added, a unit of information, a record, a data element, whatever. The sentence is correct in a certain context. If anything, the choice of the word 'information' is what needs correction, the whole 'information' is possibly not duplicated, only individual elements of it might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use the pro-form "one" to refer to part of an uncountable mass. You need a unit, such as "add a new item" or "add a new piece of information".

Incidentally, even for a countable antecedent "add only new one" would be ungrammatical: you would need and article: "add a new one". I'm not quite sure what to do with your "only".

Comment: For the last sentence, you can't use *only. Only one* functions in much the same way as an article, so it would go back to your first example and be "add only one new item".

Comment: Thanks Andrew. You are right, of course; but I don't think dt1510 meant _only_ in that way: I think they meant it in the sense of _don't do anything other than add an item_.

Comment: In that case, it would apply to *add:* "only add a new one." [Feel free to add these comments into your answer if they help; there's no point in my duplicating your answer to include them myself.]

Comment: So how could I refer to the information in: "Do not duplicate the information add only new [stuff]."? The word 'stuff' does not fit in the sentence especially in formal text. Other words like 'item' are countable.

Comment: @dt1510: you could say _add only new information_, though the repetition of _information_ is a little ugly. _Data_ is another possibility. But there isn't a pro-form like _one_ that can be used here.